Can I add parameters in Jenkins Shared library?
I am creating jenkinsjob using Job DSL and want to create parameters (defined in a params.properties file in the same path) while the pipeline job is created. Is it possible ?
pipelineJob('test-job') {
  displayName 'TEST pipeline'
  
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            credentials 'xxxxx'
            url 'https://github.com/test/test-jenkins.git'
          }
          branch 'main'
        }
      }
      scriptPath('mypipelineCode')
    }
  }
}

content of param.properties
stringParam('NAME', 'myName', 'Enter your name')
choiceParam('AGE', ['10-20','20-30','30-40'], 'Select the age')

How can I use the param.properties to create pipeline job that has above 2 parameters ?

As per documentation this is not directly possible as parameters in the pipelineJob context does not support a propertiesFile argument as seen here
However - there might be an option to inject those together with all the other pipeline code directly as part of a buildPipelineTrigger that does support the propertiesFile as seen here. So in theory you could build a "trigger" job to fire up your real one and load in the desired inputs and parameters as part of it. I know it's not what you asked for specifically but it's the closest I could find.
P.S. I have tried ingesting the parameters file into global vars and even create a specific global var with a "parameter" format but those don't seem to be correctly interpreted into XML so I doubt they would work as intended in a pipeline. Example code below:
pipelineJob('test-job') {
  displayName 'TEST pipeline'
  environmentVariables {
    propertiesFile('./param.properties')
    env('PARAM', "choiceParam(\'AGE\', [\'10-20\',\'20-30\',\'30-40\'], \'Select the age\')")
  }
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            credentials 'xxxxx'
            url 'https://github.com/test/test-jenkins.git'
          }
          branch 'main'
        }
      }
      scriptPath('mypipelineCode')
    }
  }
  parameters {
    '$PARAM'
  }
}

I have used Job DSL Playground to test out the code.

Thanks for the reply, I am looking to pass the parameters through a file from shared path and use that in multiple pipelines. With the one you suggested I will have to pass the param inside the pipelinejob defination as well which I dont want. Is it possible?

Anything is possible :D -- The concept would be to create a "seed job" that creates multiple other jobs for you based on a certain configuration (that you would typically store in git). In that way you could potentially refer a properties file and pass it onward to the job that are created. JCasC usually helps in this instance and you can find an example of a seed job here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jobs/pipeline.yaml
